# Measure disk usage by node app

Tags: node.js

In the same way as [`process.memoryUsage`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) helps you measure the memory your app is using, or [`process.cpuUsage`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cpuusage_previousvalue).

**Is there a way to identify the amount of disk space an app is using?**

(It could be by making use of an external process, no problem with that.)

To clarify a bit, the disk usage I'm talking about is for instance when your app write logs, temporary or regular files. Not dependencies or the code size itself.

Comment: Do you need only the disk I/O usage of your application or from all apps running on host?

Comment: @itsUndefined just for this app.